# Trying to get nerdamer to work in react native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can't get `nerdamer` to work correctly in my react native project. When I write the functions for `nerdamer` the way it is shown on `nerdamer's` website it gives me either undefined is not object or `nerdamer` is not a function.

I have tried rewriting the `nerdamer` functions as `nerdamer.nerdamer(equation)`. Also writing it as `nerdamer.solve(equation, variable)` and `nerdamer.Solve.solve(equation, variable)`.

```
import {nerdamer, Algebra, Calculus, Solve, Extra} from "nerdamer";

equation = nerdamer('f=m*a');
solution = equation.solveFor('a');
console.log(solution.toString());
```

When I use this code in a browser it prints `a=f*m^(-1)`. But when I test it in my react native app it throws

> (0,_nerdamer.nerdamer) is not a function. (In
>   '(0,_nerdamer.nerdamer)('f=m*a')','(0,_nerdamer.nerdamer)' is
>   undefined)

How am I supposed to be writing my `nerdamer` code in my project?

Comment: Please share the address of the module.

Comment: What is the address of a module/where do I find it?

Comment: This is where you downloaded the nerdamer module.

Comment: npm install nerdamer is what I used. It is also on nerdamer.com

Comment: This module is not available in `react-native` and is only available in `react`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use nerdamer like this (you need to import them above everything) :

```
import nerdamer from'nerdamer/nerdamer.core.js'
import 'nerdamer/Algebra.js'
import 'nerdamer/Calculus.js'
import 'nerdamer/Solve.js'
```

Nerdamer use module.export & you can import it easily like a regular module. Since there is no module.export in other modules, you can't import them like this but the codes is needed. I tested the example below from its docs & it worked :

```
let sol = nerdamer.solveEquations(['x+y=1', '2*x=6', '4*z+y=6']);
console.log(sol.toString());
//x,3,y,-2,z,2
```